# How do I draw a log log or semi log graph in a normal graph?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

Say I have a function $y=f(x)$. Now how can I change the function to $y=g(x)$ so that when $y=g(x)$ is plotted in a normal graph it looks like the semi log or log log graph of the old $y=f(x)$.

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you transform points in one coordinate system to the other?  What about a transformation for a single point?

Comment: At first I thought replacing x by log(x) will do but it didn't (for semi-log graph). Then i tried bunch of other stuff but i didn't know what i was doing so none of those worked either. I don't know what to do exactly.

Comment: I also tried applying log on both sides of the equation for log-log graph but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing a formula, try to derive one.  Suppose that $y_0=f(x_0)$ for some points in the $(x,y)$-plane.  Let $(r_0,s_0)$ be the corresponding points in the log-log or semilog planes.  Then, there are formulas $r_0=h(x_0)$ and $s_0=k(y_0)$.  So, then $k^{-1}(s_0)=f(h^{-1}(r_0))$ is your desired formula.  You can then solve for $s_0$ to get $s=k(f(h^{-1}(r)))$ to construct your graph.

Answer (score 0):

For a semi-log graph ( log in the $x$ axis and linear in the $y$ axis) replace $x$ with $10^x$, i,e,. plot $y=f(10^x)$. The $x$ value in the horizontal axis should correspond to $10^x$ in the semi-log graph (like $1, 2, 3, \cdots$ goes to $10, 100, 1000, \cdots$).

For the case of log in the $y$ axis and linear in the $x$ axis, keep $x$ as it is but instead of $y=f(x)$ plot $y=\log(f(x))$.

For log-log graph do both, and plot $y=\log(f(10^x))$.

Here $\log$ is 10-based.